# Is it possible suppress save message for undo-tree?

Tags: message, undo-tree-mode

When I save my any file I am working on I always see following message, I believe this is related to my `unto-tree` configuration.

`Wrote /home/alper/.emacs.d/undo/.!home!alper!current_folder!__init__.py.~undo-tree~`

---

**[Q]** Is it possible suppress this message (saving `undo-tree`) somehow?

My config file:

```
(global-undo-tree-mode 1)
(setq undo-tree-auto-save-history t)
(setq undo-tree-history-directory-alist '(("." . "~/.emacs.d/undo")))

(defmacro with-suppressed-message (&rest body)
  "Suppress new messages temporarily in the echo area and the `*Messages*' buffer while BODY is evaluated."
  (declare (indent 0))
  (let ((message-log-max nil))
    `(with-temp-message (or (current-message) "") ,@body)))

(defun save-all ()
  (interactive)
  ;(save-some-buffers t)
  ;(recentf-save-list)
  (with-suppressed-message (save-some-buffers t))
  (message "")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`undo-tree-save-history` calls `write-region`.  In this example, we suppress the `Wrote ...` message entirely using an `:around` advice.  Here are the steps used to verify the answer works as advertised:

**STEP 1**:  Launch a recent public release of Emacs 26.3 -- without any user-configuration, aka `emacs -Q`

**STEP 2**:  Download the library undo-tree, which was last updated 01/29/2020 from the following link:  https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/undo-tree-0.7.4.el

**STEP 3**:  From within Emacs, open the newly downloaded und-tree library file and then type `M-x eval-buffer`

**STEP 4**:  Create a **new** file-visiting-buffer by typing `M-x find-file` or its keyboard shortcut equivalent `C-x C-f` and give it a filename using a path to a working directory (where there is nothing of critical importance); e.g., `~/Desktop/scratch.el`.  Assuming that the file was new, there will be a message in the echo-area as follows:  `(New file)`.  Now, write the file to the hard-drive by typing `M-x save-buffer` or use the keyboard shortcut equivalent of `C-x C-s`.  The message in the echo area at this point will be something similar to:  `Wrote /Users/HOME/Desktop/scratch.el`

**Step 5**:  Copy the following snippets in the code-block directly below and paste them into the file-visiting-buffer described in the step immediately above; e.g., paste everything into the file-visiting-buffer `~/Desktop/scratch.el`.  Now, type `M-x eval-buffer`.  Do **NOT** save the file at this time -- i.e., leave the file-visiting-buffer in a *modified* state.

```lisp
(global-undo-tree-mode 1)
(setq undo-tree-auto-save-history t)
(setq undo-tree-history-directory-alist '(("." . "~/.emacs.d/undo")))

(defun my-undo-tree-save-history (undo-tree-save-history &rest args)
  (let ((message-log-max nil)
        (inhibit-message t))
    (apply undo-tree-save-history args)))

(advice-add 'undo-tree-save-history :around 'my-undo-tree-save-history)

(global-set-key [f5] (lambda ()
                       (interactive)
                       (let ((message-log-max nil)
                             (inhibit-message t))
                         (save-some-buffers t))))
```

**STEP 6**:  At this point in time, the file-visiting-buffer (e.g., `~/Desktop/scratch.el`) should still be in a *modified* state.  Now, let us test out the newly defined keyboard shortcut by pressing the `f5` key.  Watch the mode-line closely -- i.e., when we press the `f5` key, the far-left of the mode-line will change from *modified* `-:**-` to *unmodified* `-:---`.  However, we should not have seen anything appearing in the echo area related to pressing the above-mentioned key.

**STEP 7**:  Switch to the `*Messages*` buffer and see what is there:

```
For information about GNU Emacs and the GNU system, type C-h C-a.
You can run the command ‘eval-buffer’ with M-x ev-b RET
(New file)
Wrote /Users/HOME/Desktop/scratch.el
Mark set
You can run the command ‘eval-buffer’ with M-x ev-b RET
```

Comment: I have added the code but still I am facing with the same issue :-( Should I remove `(setq undo-tree-auto-save-history t)`?

Comment: Sorry there were problems with the initial tests -- when you get a chance, please feel free to try out the latest revised answer.

Comment: Thank you for depth answer.

I cannot use F* keys in emacs. Can I bind [f5]'s behavior into `C-x C-s` ? I have defined the functions as follows: https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/56c3eda3627b5bd567c7976de332caa1 // I have tried with my `emacs --daemon` and it works

Comment: Here is an example of how to rebind `C-x C-s` to your liking and also demonstrates how to convert my *lambda* example into a separate function:  `(defun my-save-all () "My doc-string." (interactive) (let ((message-log-max nil) (inhibit-message t)) (save-some-buffers t))) (define-key ctl-x-map "\C-s" 'my-save-all)`