# emacs get frozen due to error reading undo-tree history

Tags: undo-tree-mode, frozen-emacs

Once every hour, or when I open a new file; I am usually getting error related to `reading undo-tree history`, which lead emacs daemon to frozen, and everytime I have to re-start the `emacs`.

The error I am having, where Emacs get frozen:

`Error reading undo-tree history from "/home/alper/.emacs.d/undo/.!home!alper!personalize!emacs_q_git_edit.el.~undo-tree~"`

How could I prevent `emacs` to get frozen due the `Error reading undo-tree history from its file`? Please note that when `emacs` frozen I was unable to debug it to invest it further.

---

The way I installed `emacs`:

```bash
mkdir -p ~/tools && cd ~/tools
git clone git://git.savannah.gnu.org/emacs.git && cd emacs
./autogen.sh
./configure --with-x-toolkit=yes --with-x-toolkit=no --with-native-compilation
make -j$(nproc)
sudo mkdir -p /opt/ss
sudo rm -f /opt/ss/*
sudo ln -s ~/tools/emacs/lib-src/emacsclient /opt/ss/
sudo ln -s ~/tools/emacs/src/emacs /opt/ss/
```

---

my configuration relevant to `undo-tree`, [related](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/59951/18414):

```lisp
(require 'undo-tree)
(setq undo-tree-auto-save-history t)
(global-undo-tree-mode t)
(setq undo-tree-auto-save-history t)
(setq undo-tree-history-directory-alist '(("." . "~/.emacs.d/undo")))
(global-set-key "\C-x\C-v" 'undo-tree-visualize)
(require 'linum)
(defun undo-tree-visualizer-update-linum (&rest args)
    (linum-update undo-tree-visualizer-parent-buffer))
(advice-add 'undo-tree-visualize-undo :after #'undo-tree-visualizer-update-linum)
(advice-add 'undo-tree-visualize-redo :after #'undo-tree-visualizer-update-linum)
(advice-add 'undo-tree-visualize-undo-to-x :after #'undo-tree-visualizer-update-linum)
(advice-add 'undo-tree-visualize-redo-to-x :after #'undo-tree-visualizer-update-linum)
(advice-add 'undo-tree-visualizer-mouse-set :after #'undo-tree-visualizer-update-linum)
(advice-add 'undo-tree-visualizer-set :after #'undo-tree-visualizer-update-linum)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to disable undo-in-region. It is buggy and responsible for slowing down.

```
(setq undo-tree-enable-undo-in-region nil)
```

Comment: Hopefully it will fix the problem I am having. I will update if I still face with the same error even `undo-tree-enable-undo-in-region` is disabled

Comment: I should do `(setq undo-tree-enable-undo-in-region nil)` right?

Comment: right. I  updated the code in the message.

Comment: Is there any way to kill undo-tree when this kind of bug frozes emacs?

Comment: not to my knowledge ...

Comment: Assuming you're on a Unix-like system, you can try `kill -USR2 <pid>` for the Emacs process ID, which has much the same effect as typing `C-g` if you'd already enabled `debug-on-quit` (n.b. it does in fact enable that variable).  Or `killall -e -i -USR2 emacs` (read the man page to see what that will do).

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, and I figure documenting my diagnostic process here might help people with this sort of problem, as it applies for other emacs issues.

I used ctrl-G to stop the save operation, then set the variable `debug-on-quit` to `t`, saved again and then hit ctrl-g to find the stack trace and find that the issue was caused by the undo-tree-mode.

I then ran `m-x undo-tree-mode` to disable the undo tree mode, which allowed me to save successfully.

After this I set `debug-on-quit` back to `nil`.

It's not a permanent fix, but lets me save without having to quit emacs, recompile or anything like that.